# Mantis Bug Tracker Export Selected Issues

Tags: export, mantis

I have been trying to export a part of the issue list to XML. It seems that the selection has no effect: all issues are exported instead. Any idea of how it could be done?

[image]

Comment: Is the problem only with XML export? Does eg CSV function correctly?

Comment: With CSV the same thing

Answer (score 1):

The checkboxes are provided to select issues for bulk actions listed in the select box (drop-down) towards the end of the table. The button actions on the top of the table does not respect the checkbox selection. This is the expected behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but I do not find the 'expected behavior' useful. I have about 600 items in the list, I only need to export a few last ones. This is certainly something to be changed if Mantis wants to remain a player.

Comment: Please submit a feature request in their bug tracker: https://www.mantisbt.org/bugs